# How to sum up large number of elements in a table quickly?

Tags: performance-tuning

I have been using *Mathematica* for some time now but I have a feeling that I am not using it as efficiently as it could be.

I have the following problem which I am unable to figure out and it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction:

I have a function which is of the following form:

```
f[x_]:= Total[A1/(A2+x),Infinity];
```

where `A1` and `A2` are very large arrays (2500x2500 real numbers)
(Sorry for the way I wrote the function but I haven't figured out how to insert code into the question (not very good at this type of typesetting))

The problem is when I want to create another list (large list) of values of `f[x]`. It seems that Total is what slows things down here and I was wondering if there is a way to replace Total with something faster.

Any clues?

Comment: Are A1 and A2 different each time you call f or are they constant?

Comment: they are constant. These are 2D tables created using Table, if this is of any help.

Comment: It's under one second for 2000 `x` values, with A1 and A2 being lists {1,2000}. What is your expected speed?

Comment: well yes, you are right, f[x] takes under 1 second, but if i need to apply f to 2000 values of x then the time increases significantly. I have a feeling that there might be nothing else to do to speed this up. But hope is the last to go :)

Comment: Hang, on I just read previous comment earlier. It takes under a second for one value of x. For 2000+ values it takes about 10 minutes. This is what I am hoping to improve. More precisely if I do: ParallelTable[f[x],{x,1,2000}], it takes about 10 mins.

Comment: Mine is very fast, I can run about 10000 x values per second. What hardware are you using?

Comment: I have a laptop with a 2.4 core i5 procesor and 4 Gb of ram

Comment: my guess is it's the paralleltable. Why bother? each iteration is fast, the entire 10 minutes is probably overhead trying to call a thread

Comment: @user72409 actually, what are the exact sizes of `A1` and `A2`? You said 2D Array, we've been using single arrays in answers...

Comment: A1 and A2 are 2500x2500 (but this is an example, it could be more but let's go with this because I know that it takes about 10 mins on my machine). But as I said before, these remain constant. This was the whole idea. I wanted to precalculate them in order to gain speed, and I did but the final Table[f[x],{x,1,2500}], this takes 10 mins to calculate.

Comment: 6,000,000 >> 2000

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that your arrays `a1` and `a2` are not packed, which would case a considerable slow-down.

Observe:

```
f[x_] := Total[a1/(a2 + x), -1]

n = Ceiling @ Sqrt @ 2000;

a1 = RandomReal[{-99, 99}, {n, n}];
a2 = RandomReal[{-99, 99}, {n, n}];

Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {a1, a2}
```

> {True, True}

```
Table[f[i], {i, 1, 50000}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.0296018

```
{a1, a2} = Developer`FromPackedArray /@ {a1, a2};

Table[f[i], {i, 1, 50000}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 66.1285161

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_, a1_, a2_] := Total[a1/(a2 + x), Infinity];
{a1, a2} = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2000}];
Timing[f[#, a1, a2] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2000]][[1]]
```

Takes under one second in my machine

Comment: Odd, I tried `f[x_] = Total[a1/(a2 + x), Infinity]` followed by `Timing[f[#] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2000]][[1]]` and it is about 4 seconds on my machine vs 0.25 for your solution. I would have thought that precomputing the `Total` would have been faster. Any ideas?

Comment: @tkott loss of packing

Comment: @tkott evaluate `SetSystemOptions[PackedArrayOptions->UnpackMessage->True]` and you'll see :)

Comment: @acl or shorter: `On["Packing"]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, @ acl ahh, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Table` instead of `ParallelTable`?

Anyway, here's an ugly way to get `f` a bit faster:

```
a1 = RandomReal[{0.1, 10}, 10000];
a2 = RandomReal[{0.1, 10}, 10000];
```

Original definition:

```
f[x_] := Total[a1/(a2 + x), Infinity]
```

slightly faster:

```
fc = Compile[
   {{x, _Real}, {a1, _Real, 1}, {a2, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{t = 0.},
    Do[t = t + a1[[i]]/(a2[[i]] + x), {i, 1, Length[a1]}];
    t
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

Table[f[N@x], {x, 1, 2000}]; // Timing
Table[fc[N@x, a1, a2], {x, 1, 2000}]; // Timing
(*
{0.370212, Null}
{0.164774, Null}
*)
```

One possibility as to why `ParallelTable` is slower: it unpacks. Try:

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "PackedArrayOptions" -> "UnpackMessage" -> True];

a1 = RandomReal[{0.1, 10}, 10000];
a2 = RandomReal[{0.1, 10}, 10000];

ParallelTable[f[x], {x, 1, 2000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[f[x], {x, 1, 2000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is also added overhead when using `ParallelTable`. As tkott mentions in a comment, it would be helpful to know what `a1` and `a2` actually are (their dimensions).

Comment: you forgot the `Total` part :)

Comment: I am afraid that I do not understand how you made f faster. Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: @user72409 sorry I botched the pasting and did not actually paste the faster version. In any case I don't know if this will remain faster for such large arrays (and it needs modification to work with 2D arrays anyway; perhaps you could mention this in your question!)

Comment: @acl Thank you fo the extensive post. I have never used Compile successfully but I will try and give it another go.

Comment: @acl I tried running my problem using Table instead of ParallelTable but the latter is considerably faster. I get 649 seconds vs a lot more for the case of Table (I actually stopped it after it passed the 10 minute mark)

Comment: @acl to me it seems that Total isn't very fast, or it is slower in this case due to something that I can't see. There is a very large amount of elements to be added. Is there an alternative way to add the elements of a Table, other than Total, For loops or Sum?

Comment: this (how to speed it up) might depend on the details. unpacking might be involved for instance. Could you post some code that produces `a1` and `a2` in the form you need them, then uses `f` the way you use it?